# Positioning elements in one line

Tags: html, css, mobile

i have problem with displaing divs inline on mobiles. So code works fine in PC's but when i visit my website in mobile i just dont display divs in right way.

Image div is above the div with text (should be inline). This is not case of width because even if i change width of image to just 5px, this small image is still above not right next to.

Example: http://www.filmypodobnedo.pl/matrix/

Whole thing is about listing of similar movies to chosen one (in example matrix), listed movies (IMAGE + TEXT should be displayed inline, that works on PC but not on mobile).

HTML:

```
<div class="podobny_film">
<div id="zdjecie_podobne">
<img class="featured-project-image" width="100" height="150" alt="Filmy podobne do Equilibrium" src="http://www.filmypodobnedo.pl/photos/Equilibrium.jpg">
</div>
<div id="tekst_podobne">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.podobny_film {
float: left;
width: 80%;
color: #555555;
border-style: dashed;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
padding: 10px;
}
#zdjecie_podobne {     
width: 120px;
float: left;
}
#tekst_podobne {
width: 75%;
float: left;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block` to `#zdjecie_podobne` and `#tekst_podobne`

Answer (score 0):

The div "podobny_film" contains div "zdjecie_podobne" with fixed pixel width and div "tekst_podobne" with percentage width. Try to use a percentage width for the div "zdjecie_podobne" and for the image as well, then it should not break.

```
#zdjecie_podobne {     
width:24%; /*together with tekst_podobne that's 99% so be aware of any margins or paddings that might sum up > 100%!*/
float: left;
}

.featured-project-image { width:100%; }
```

Comment: That doesnt work :/

I think that it ist matter of width or size of column. Because even if I set image width jus to 1 px, this picture-pixel will be stil above text.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :) :

```
  #zdjecie_podobne {     
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    }
    #tekst_podobne {
    width: 75%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```